# JavaFX: Set the color of a ProgressIndicator's text label

Tags: java, css, javafx, colors, progress-indicator

I want to change the color of the text label, that is attached to the ProgressIndicator, because the default text color is black, and my background is also black.

So far i've tried this:

```
ProgressIndicator pg = new ProgressIndicator(0);
pg.setStyle("-fx-foreground-color: #FF00000");
```

but it didn't seem to work.

Important to note: I use the ProgressIndicator in Determinate-Mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not tested, but according to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#progressindicator), you should be able to do

```
.progress-indicator .percentage {
    -fx-fill: #ff0000 ;
}
```

in an external style sheet.

(Note you also seemed to have too many digits in your color spec.)